On the permutation consistency condition in the Kolmogorov extension theorem
I am trying to understand the Kolmogorov extension theorem (KET). Wikipedia states the following two necessary consistency conditions for the probability measures $\nu_{t_1,\cdots,t_k}$:
$$\nu_{t_{\pi(1)},\cdots,t_{\pi(k)}} (F_{\pi(1)} \times \cdots \times F_{\pi(k)}) 
= \nu_{t_1,\cdots,t_k} (F_1 \times \cdots \times F_k)  \tag{K1}$$
for all permutations $\pi$ on $\{1,2, \cdots,k\}$ and
$$\nu_{t_1,\cdots,t_k}(F_1\times \cdots \times F_k) \\
= \nu_{t_1,\cdots,t_k, t_{k+1}, \cdots, t_{k+m}}(F_1\times \cdots \times F_k\times \mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times\mathbb{R}^n )\tag{K2}$$
for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, where the set on the right hand side has a total of $k + m$ factors.
The same conditions are stated in Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications by Bernt Øksendal. Øksendal references Stochastic Processes by John Lamperti.
The proof of Lamperti for the KET is not complete, but he mentions where the consistency become relevent. The argument is in essence the following. The notation for the probability space to be found is $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. For the sample space $\Omega$, its elements $\omega\in\Omega$ are mappings $\omega(\cdot):T\to\mathbb{R}$. The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ will be generated by all sets of the form
$$E=\{\omega\in\Omega:(\omega(t_1),\ldots,\omega(t_n))\in C\}=\Phi^{-1}_{t_1,\ldots,t_n}(C),\tag{1}$$
where C is some Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is any finite ordered subset of $T$ (Lamperti allows for $T$ to be any set, but I guess the previous statement requires for $T$ at least to be such that an order can be defined for its elements). The sets $E$ are called cylinder sets. Also, $\Phi_{t_1,\ldots,t_n}$ is the mapping from the probability space $\Omega$ into the n-tuple $(X(t_1,\omega),\ldots,X(t_n,\omega))$. The finite-dimensional distributions of the process $X$ are the probability measured defined by
$$P_{t_1,\ldots,t_n}(C)=P(\Phi^{-1}_{t_1,\ldots,t_n}(C)),\tag{2}$$
where C is any measurable set in $S^n$ (While Lamperti previously defines $S$ to be any set, this proof assumes $S=\mathbb{R}$, if I'm not mistaken). Lamperti states now two obstacles to overcome, the first of which involves the consistency conditions. Namely, if two different subsets of $T$ and/or Borel sets $C$ can be used to define the same cylinder set $E$, it must be verified that the proposed finite-dimensional distributions assign the same measure to $E$ regardless of which representation is chosen.
The last part above makes perfect sense to me and I also find it kind of intuitive that we need (K2). However, I fail to see how (K1) becomes relevant. For (1), $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is assumed to be an ordered subset of $T$. This effectively renders all measures $P_{t_1,\ldots,t_l}$ with some $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,l\}$ such that $i<j$, but $t_i>t_j$ unused. Hence, this makes me think that the first consistency condition would only make sense if we drop the requirement that $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is an ordered subset of $T$. This could be useful if there is no "natural" order on $T$ as there is for example for $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.
Can someone clarify please?

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}\newcommand\la{\lambda}$We want to construct a family $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ of random variables such that for any natural $k$ and any distinct $t_1,\dots,t_k$ in $T$ and any appropriate $F_1,\dots,F_k$ we have
$$P(X_{t_1}\in F_1,\dots,X_{t_k}\in F_k)=\nu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(F_1\times\cdots\times F_k). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
This implies that, for any permutation $\pi$ on $\{1,\dots,k\}$ we have
$$\nu_{t_{\pi(1)},\dots,t_{\pi(k)}}
(F_{\pi(1)}\times\cdots\times F_{\pi(k)})
=P(X_{t_{\pi(1)}}\in F_{\pi(1)},\dots,X_{t_{\pi(k)}}\in F_{\pi(k)}) \\
=P(X_{t_1}\in F_1,\dots,X_{t_k}\in F_k)=\nu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(F_1\times\cdots\times F_k).$$
So, your condition (K1) is necessary for \eqref{1}.
Also, without (K1) the theorem would not hold. E.g., suppose that $\la$ and $\mu$ are two different probability distributions over $\R^2$ such that each marginal of $\la$ and each marginal of $\mu$ is some probability distribution $\nu$ over $\R$. Suppose also that $T=\{1,2\}$, $\nu_1=\nu_2=\nu$, $\nu_{1,2}=\la$, and
$$\nu_{2,1}(F_2\times F_1)=\mu(F_1\times F_2)$$
for all Borel subsets $F_1,F_2$ of $\R$. Then (K2) will hold, but (K1) will not, even though (K1) is necessary.
(Actually, $(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ is not assumed to be ordered.)

The OP is insisting that $(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ be "ordered", apparently meaning that we have $\nu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}$ only if  $t_1<\dots<t_k$. However, then

Condition (K1) will have no meaning for any nontrivial permutation $\pi$ -- whereas, as shown above, (K1) cannot be dropped.

Also, in general, the index set $T$ does not have to be totally ordered. It may be any set whatsoever. In particular, $T$ may be a subset of $\R^d$ for $d\ge2$, and then the family $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ of random variables is called a random field.


On the other hand, if $T$ is a subset of $\R$ or, more generally, $T$ is totally ordered, then indeed we can do with just $\nu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}$ with $t_1<\dots<t_k$. However, then we will have to modify condition (K2) -- which involves "dropping" the last $m$ of the $k+m$ coordinates -- by allowing one to "drop" any one (and hence any subset) of the coordinates. Moreover, then condition (K1) can be omitted (and, as noted above, it will not then make sense anyway).

Thank you for your answer. I unchecked the response as it previously did answer my question, but now it doesn't anymore. The argument that we'd like to drop any of the $m$ coordinates, which requires K1, makes sense to me and answers my question. The assumption that $(t_1,\ldots,t_k)$ is ordered, was an integral part of my question. Maybe because I am an engineer, I give it too much value, but considering the application of stochastic processes (which can be thought of as evolving in time), it does make sense to me to consider the theorem with the restriction of $(t_1,\ldots,t_k)$ being

ordered. In this case, I still fail to see the relevance of considering expressions of the form $\nu_{t_i,t_j}$, where $t_i>t_j$, since there'd be no reason to ever consider this value as it goes against the fundamental assumption that the times are ordered in an increasing fashion. However, when dropping that assumption, your example is very clear to me, thank you for providing it.

@FelixCrazzolara : I have added comments on the "ordered" condition.

thank you for the addition. Also, for pointing out that we'd have to modify K2 in that case. I missed that dropping any coordinate, which is not the last one, would requires shifting it to the end first, in order to use K2, hence requiring K1.
